# What is the dialect feature in British English where "W" is pronounced as "Y"?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

It is very rare but I've heard some people from Great Britain pronouncing it like that for some reason.

For instance:

- He said "However" pronouncing it as "Hoyiever".
- He said "Let him down" pronouncing it "Let him doyn".
- He said "He freaked out" pronouncing "He freaked oyit".

It's quite strange although they have numerous things in their accent!

(You may ask where I heard that one, it's from [Jim Browning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Browning_(YouTuber)) if you are familiar with him.)

Which dialects pronounce it this way? And what is this called?

Comment: I think it's more the diphthong /aʊ/ , and not just the consonant; asking why is probably not possible to answer. It's a regional accent, AFAIK., and dialects and accents are learned from the cradle.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ I'm actually searching for someone British and who is well-acquainted with it ... if it sounds familiar to them, that's all xD

Comment: AJ Ellis in his 1868 book [*Early English Pronunciation*](https://archive.org/stream/onearlyenglishpr00elliuoft/onearlyenglishpr00elliuoft_djvu.txt) wrote: "Properly speaking there is no uniformity. Not only will a practised ear tell the village in a district from which a speaker hails, but a more accurate examination will shew that families in the same village do not speak exactly alike."

Comment: Your examples sound like a Northern Irish accent.

Comment: @Greybeard That tracks—[Jim Browning is from Northern Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Browning_(YouTuber)). So the United Kingdom but not Great Britain.

Comment: It is a common pronunciation in the North of Ireland.

Comment: My CV is for lack of clarity. I'm not sure if the NI pronunciation some have assumed or the exaggerated upper-class accent of the 1930s, very different (with _down_ perhaps more usually represented 'dahn'). OP needs to use the IPA.

Comment: We should try to help the OP with IPA, not criticize. Vote to re-open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linguists have noted the existence of pronunciations of the "mouth" diphthong with a "fronted" offglide at the end (one that sounds comparatively less like a "w" sound and more like a "y" sound) in several distinct accents of English.

The linguist John Wells wrote two blog posts in 2010 about the alleged usage of a pronunciation similar to this by Queen Elizabeth II:

- "[the myth of maɨθ](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/12/myth-of-ma.html)", 8 December 2010
- "[countless thousands](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/12/countless-thousands.html)", 27 December 2010

Wells observes that even when fronting is not present, the vowel may not be very rounded. A blog post by the linguist Geoff Lindsay transcribes a pronunciation of this diphthong in Charles's speech as [ɐɤ] ("[The King’s Speech: Charles III’s RP accent](https://www.englishspeechservices.com/blog/king-charles-rp-accent/)", *Speech Talk* blog, September 15, 2022)

More relevantly though to your example of Jim Browning, Wells also has a page titled "[links to recordings of English accents and dialects](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/accentsanddialects/)" for his book *Accents of English* with some descriptions of the recordings, including the following note about Northern Ireland:

> Among the special Ulster characteristics are a MOUTH diphthong which ends in a central, usually unrounded, quality, [ʌɨ]

That supports [Stephen Manistre](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/452823/stephen-manistre)'s [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/588663/what-is-the-dialect-feature-in-british-english-where-w-is-pronounced-as-y/588688#588688) ("It is a common pronunciation in the North of Ireland"), which a moderator deleted and converted to a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/588663/what-is-the-dialect-feature-in-british-english-where-w-is-pronounced-as-y/588690#comment1476662_588663).

(The audio on that page only works on some browsers. Wells advises Internet Explorer.)